# How does "ton logon" in Mark 1:45 compare with "ton logon" in Mark 2:2?

Tags: mark

**Mark 1:45**

> "But he went out and began to talk freely about it, and to spread **the news**, so that Jesus could no longer openly enter a town, but was out in desolate places, and the people were coming to him from every quarter." ESV. My emphasis. [the news/*ton logon*].

**Mark 2:2**

> "And many were gathered together, so that there was no more room, not even at the door. And he was preaching **the word** to them". ESV. My emphasis. [the word/*ton logon*].

Surely in Mark's writing he had a reason as to why he put "*ton logon*" and then repeated it in close proximity to the first occasion. The reason being that the meanings  on these two
occasions overlapped.

1. What might Mark's  meaning be?

The ESV makes a difference between them by putting "the news" for one and "the word" for the other.

2. What might justify this change in the way "*ton logon*" is translated?

Comment: Up-voted +1. For Mark 1:45, Wycliffe has 'publish the word' and Bishop's Bible has 'publish the saying'.

Comment: ἐλάλει αὐτοῖς τὸν λόγον Mark 4:33 "this saying is commonly reported " KJV

Comment: διεφημίσθη ὁ λόγος Mattews 28:15 Bishop's Bible has 'this saying is noysed'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that "ton logon" in both Mark 1:45 and Mark 2:2 refers to the message of the gospel, quite simply.  This can be readily deduced because in both cases we have:

- Mark 1:45 - He [Jesus] began to proclaim much and to spread abroad **the word** ...
- Mark 2:2 - ... He [Jesus] was speaking **the word** to them.

In Jesus keynote address/sermon at the beginning of His earthly ministry, He stated the purposed and intention of His preaching as per Luke 4:18 -

> “The Spirit of the Lord is on Me, because He has anointed Me to preach
> good news to the poor. ...

Thus, when Jesus "proclaimed the word", He preach the good news of the Gospel of grace and salvation.